# Power Automate permissions to create item in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions, power-automate, flow

I have an Instant Workflow with the following setting:

**SharePoint**

Run-only users will be asked to provide their own connection to this connector.

I have a 'Create Item' action in the workflow with a 'System Account' connection. The System Account has full access to the site.

When user account has edit access to list, the item gets created. When user access is changed to read on the list, the workflow errors with 'Access Denied'. I thought as the 'Create Item' action has the system account, this shouldn't be a problem and an item should have been created.

1. Why is this?
2. How can I get it to work without giving the user edit access?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Run-only users permissions for SharePoint connector, all actions with standard SharePoint connector will run with individual user permissions.

As users are having read permissions in SharePoint list, they cannot create new items in the list.

You can try either of below solutions:

1. Run all SharePoint connector actions using system account connection
2. Grant **Contribute** or higher permissions to users on the SharePoint list.

Contribute permissions are enough for creating / updating / deleting SharePoint list items.

Comment: Because the 'Create Item' action is set to system account, I would expect it to use this. So what is the point of adding the system account against actions?

Comment: I think when you use Run-only users permissions for specific connector, all actions from that connector will use the connection provided by the end users.